# Relation between two Fox-H function with positive and negative argument

Tags: special-functions

Is there the relation between Fox-H function with positive argument and Fox-H function with negative argument? My question is attached in the image. [image]

Comment: Is this a Mathematica software question or a mathematics question? If the latter, it belongs in [math.se], where it may receive more relevant answers.